# python multiplication quiz invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, multiplication

I have this python multiplication quiz.

```
import random

score = 0
continue = True
while continue:
    a = random.randint(1, 12)
    b = random.randint(1, 12)
    product = a * b
    guess = int(input('What is '+str(a)+' times '+str(b)+'? (press "q" to quit):'))
    if guess == 'q':
        continue = False
    if guess != product:
        print('Sorry, this is wrong. It should be '+str(product)+'.')
        continue = False
    if guess == product:
        print('Good job. You got it right.')

print('Thanks for playing! You scored '+str(score)+'.')
```

It keeps saying `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when I try to run it at the line `continue = True`.

Before adding the `continue` query, it worked fine:

```
import random

score = 0
while True:
    a = random.randint(1, 12)
    b = random.randint(1, 12)
    product = a * b
    guess = int(input('What is '+str(a)+' times '+str(b)+'? (press "q" to quit):'))
    if guess == 'q':
        break
    if guess != product:
        print('Sorry, this is wrong. It should be '+str(product)+'.')
    if guess == product:
        print('Good job. You got it right.')

print('Thanks for playing! You scored '+str(score)+'.')
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with the line `continue = True`. From what I know this is assigning `True` to the variable `continue`. Please help!

Comment: `continue` is a keyword in Python. Try using a different variable name

Comment: `continue` is a python keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`continue` is a python keyword, like `if`, `else`, `True`, `break`, etc. so you can't assign a value to it. If you want to use this name, try `continue_` (from pep8).

Also with the `continue_` fix entering `'q'` will cause an exception because python tries to do `int('q')`, which doesn't work.

You didn't increment the score in your function, so adding `score += 1` if correct will help.

```py
import random


score = 0
continue_ = True
while continue_:
    a = random.randint(1, 12)
    b = random.randint(1, 12)
    product = a * b
    guess = input('What is '+str(a)+' times '+str(b)+'? (press "q" to quit):')
    if guess == 'q':
        break
    if int(guess) != product:
        print('Sorry, this is wrong. It should be '+str(product)+'.')
        continue_ = False
    if int(guess) == product:
        print('Good job. You got it right.')
        score += 1

print('Thanks for playing! You scored '+str(score)+'.')
```

for example will output

```py
What is 6 times 7? (press "q" to quit):42
Good job. You got it right.
What is 10 times 7? (press "q" to quit):70
Good job. You got it right.
What is 8 times 7? (press "q" to quit):56
Good job. You got it right.
What is 9 times 10? (press "q" to quit):90
Good job. You got it right.
What is 2 times 12? (press "q" to quit):24
Good job. You got it right.
What is 12 times 3? (press "q" to quit):36
Good job. You got it right.
What is 11 times 6? (press "q" to quit):66
Good job. You got it right.
What is 11 times 7? (press "q" to quit):q
Thanks for playing! You scored 8.
```

Comment: It says `Thanks for playing! You scored 0.` no matter how many questions are right.

Comment: Yeah, you didn't increment the score when you got it right. You can insert the line `score += 1` when you get it right to increment it.